# SQL JAVA JDBC deleteForCustomerID

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

This method should essentially **`delete`** a customer in the **`creditcard`** class (it's set as cascade on delete in the DB) but I'm thinking this is incorrect.

My sql statement is:

```
final static String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM creditcard WHERE customer_id = ?;";
```

Any advice would be really appreciated. I'm just not seeing where I'm going wrong with this.

```
public void deleteForCustomerID(Connection connection, Long customerID) throws SQLException, DAOException 
{
    if (customerID == null) 
    {
        throw new DAOException("Trying to delete customer with NULL ID");
    }

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try 
    {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(deleteSQL);
        ps.setLong(1, customerID);
        int rows = ps.executeUpdate();

    }
    finally {}

}
```

The code for the JUnit Test is:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteForCustomerID() throws Exception
{
    DataSource ds = DataSourceManager.getDataSource();
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
    // Do not commit changes made by this test.
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);

    CreditCardDAO dao = new CreditCardDaoImpl();

    CreditCard ccard = dao.retrieveForCustomerID(connection, customerID);
    assertNotNull(ccard);
    dao.deleteForCustomerID(connection, customerID);
    CreditCard ccard2 = dao.retrieveForCustomerID(connection, customerID);
    assertNull(ccard2);

    // Do not commit changes made by this test.
    connection.rollback();
    connection.setAutoCommit(true);
    connection.close();
}
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but
>   was:  at
>   org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)     at
>   org.junit.Assert.failNotNull(Assert.java:755)     at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:737)  at
>   org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:747)

Comment: Do you think that it is incorrect or did you actually run it and got unexpected behaviour? Drop the trailing semicolon from the sql command.

Comment: Which DBMS and JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: I ran it and received unexpected behaviour:java.lang.AssertionError: expected null, but was:<cs4347.jdbcProject.ecomm.entity.CreditCard@1f205aa>
 at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
 at org.junit.Assert.failNotNull(Assert.java:755)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:737)
 at org.junit.Assert.assertNull(Assert.java:747)
 at cs4347.jdbcProject.ecomm.unitTesting.dao.CreditcardDaoTest.testDeleteForCustomerID(CreditcardDaoTest.java:76)

Comment: I'm using the mysql workbench. As for JDBC Driver I am unsure what it is

Comment: Please include the code of your unit test and the exception message in your question.

Comment: think about it: how should anybody answer your question if you don't show the relevant information. An assertion in your test fails and it is not in the code you have shown. So add the test code to the question.

Comment: I did @MarkRotteveel and you're correct wero sorry for leaving it out.

Answer (score 0):

I think your deletesql string should be corrected as below. You don't need that semicolon inside quotation marks

```
   final static String deleteSQL = "DELETE FROM creditcard WHERE customer_id = ?";
```

Comment: @user3512367 Can you show us your Connection class? Do you have mySql_connector jar file in your libraries?

Comment: I do have mqy_con.. but as for Connection class, do you mean this:
url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simple_company
id=root
passwd=passwd

Comment: @user3512367 I'm asking about the connection object you're parsing to the deleteForCustomerID() method. you should have something like Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javajdbc";
        c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pass");